# Passing a FileStream as an argument to StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net

In some code for writing and reading a file first create FileStream object then pass it as an argument to StreamWrite or StreamReader, my question is why they don't just creat  StreamWrite or StreamReader ? and does each StreamWrite or StreamReader create FileStream automatically ?

```
FileStream output=new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter fileWriter=new StreamWriter(output)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is possible to instantiate a SteamWriter directly with a FilePath and a FileStream will be created automatically under the hood.

But remember that a StreamWriter is an object that is able to write to any Stream (not just FileStreams); the convenience constructor of creating a FileStream underneath the hood is normally good enough.  But if someone has some special need to open up a FileStream with very specific options set, they will first create the FileStream, then pass it to the StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write or read a file you can use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class.

```
File.ReadAllText(path);
File.WriteAllText(path,txt);
File.ReadAllLines(path);
File.WriteAllLines(path,lineArray);
```

No need to use `FileStream`..

---

To answer your question of why `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` need to be passed a `FileStream`..

So that `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` could be reused..

```
readStream(new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open));//read file stream
readStream(new NetworkStream(url));//read  newtwork stream
readStream(new MemoryStream(object));//read memory stream
```

---

```
public void readStream(StreamReader sr)//general reader method
{
//read stream
}
```

This method is so general it could read almost any stream thereby **reusing** the code..